# What sets of primes can we pick out with first-order statements?

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic

For each prime $p$, we have the algebraically closed field $\bar{\mathbb F}_p$ with the Frobenius automorphism.

Given any first-order statement with no free variables using the symbols $0,1, +, \times, -, /, \sigma(),=$, we can interpret it in $\bar{\mathbb F}_p$, interpreting the field operations to mean themselves and $\sigma$ to mean Frobenius.

For each prime, it is either true of false. This gives us a set of primes.

> What sets of primes can be described this way?

It is easy to pick out the primes whose Frobenius elements have a certain conjugacy class in in a Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$, and to pick out finite sets of primes.

Are there any sets of this type not generated by conjugacy classes in Galois groups and finite sets under the logical operations?

Comment: For some primes the interpretation of the statement might involve dividing by zero, and for others it might not. Is this a problem? Oh -- the examples I'm thinking of involve being able to talk about the number 1. I assume I'm allowed to do that? I've only just noticed it's not in your list.

Comment: 1 is definable from those operations

Comment: I should have put $1$ and $0$ on the list for clarity, but as Cody points out it doesn't matter.

Comment: These sets form a countable Boolean algebra, so one way to think about this is to characterize this Boolean algebra.

Comment: I'm still finding it difficult to interpret what the question means. How does one interpret "there exists x such that for all y with sigma(y)=y, 1/(y^2+1)!=x". This seems to me to make sense only for 50 percent of primes. 

Comment: Can we just remove "divides" from the list?

Comment: Since division is definable from multiplication in any field, you don't really need it in the language formally, which will avoid the division-by-zero issue. Alternatively, you can handle the issue either by making / a total function in some default manner, or by adopting some explicit manner of handling partial functions. But it seems easiest, since the function is definable, simply to eliminate it from the formal language, since the definable sets will be the same without it. 

Comment: OK so I now understand the question. And my gut feeling is that one can get more than primes defined by Chebotarev-like conditions. For example one can ask "does there exist $b$ such that $b^p=b+1$ and $b$ is the cube of an element $c$ with $c^p=c+2$". Although I can't prove that this is not definable using Cebotarev, I would not be at all surprised if this sort of thing, or a variant, gave a set of primes outside the Cebotarev world, because it's an assertion about a polynomial of varying degree as $p$ varies. 

Comment: Clarification: by "Cebotarev" I mean primes which, up to a finite set, are defined by Frobenius conj classes in Galois extensions of the rationals (sets of primes for which the Cebotarev density theorem says something!).

Comment: If $c^p=c+2$, then $(c^3)^{p} = (c+2)^3$, so $1 = 3c^2+3c+1$, so $p=2$. But perhaps something similar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You guessed the correct answer.
This is explained in the paper
of Mike Fried and  George Sacerdote,
*[Solving Diophantine Problems Over All Residue Class Fields of a Number Field
and All Finite Fields](http://www.math.uci.edu/~mfried/paplist-ff/annals76.pdf)*,
The Annals of Mathematics, 2nd Ser., Vol. 104, No. 2. (Sep., 1976), pp. 203-233.

Since the theory of fields lacks elimination of quantifiers in the language of rings
(the formula $\exists y,\ x=y^2$ which says that $x$ is a square cannot be expressed
directly as a polynomial condition on $x$), the authors introduce a richer language,
using the concept of Galois stratifications, which allows for elimination of quantifiers.
Geometrically, this basically means that one can eliminate quantifiers up to the level
of finite extensions of fields.

See also Chapters 30 and 31 on Galois stratifications in the book *Field arithmetic* by Mike Fried and Moshe Jarden.